# Multiple Regression

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression

[image]Are my IV multicollinear? As I ran Pearson's correlation, it shows that they are not but as I ran multiple regression, v2csprtcpt_osp was not significant with my dv, v2xel_frefair [image]

Answer (score 4):

Correlation matrix between each pairs of IVs only provides part of the picture of multi-collinearity. The actual multi-collinearity also considers the presence of the third and other IVs as well. The statistics that will better indicate multi-collinearity is called *variance inflation factor (VIF)* or its reciprocal *tolerance*. And unfortunately your software requires an upgrade to show these two sets of number.

However, you can compute them. This [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor) shows the formula. Basically, you'll need to use each of the IVs as the DV, and predict it with the rest of the IVs. Gather their $R^2$ and compute the VIF using $1 / (1-R^2)$.